# ng-init no funciona

Tags: angularjs

Tengo lo sgte :

```
<tr>
    <td>{{object.valor | number:2}}</td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="object2.valor" 
        ng-init="object2.valor=object.valor" ng-value="object.valor"/>
    </td>
</tr>

Object : {{object}}  => {valor: 15}
Object 2 : {{object2}} => {}
```

Lo curioso que en el input text si que veo el valor 15 o si modifico el input a otro numero si actualiza el valor de object2

Una alternativa que he pensado es en mi js:

```
var valor = {valor:12};
$scope.object = valor;
$scope.object2 = valor;

<input type="number" ng-model="object.valor" /
<input type="number" ng-model="object2.valor" />
```

Pero si modifico el valor de uno tb se modifica el otro, como puedo hacer que sean independientes?

Answer (score 1):

Probe tu código en una solución vacía de angular y funciona perfectamente.
Tal vez haya un error en tu código antes de llegar al ng-init que mencionas.

```js
// Code goes here
angular.module('plunker', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.object = {};
  $scope.object.valor = 15;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angularjs@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="plunker">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tr>
      <td>{{object.valor | number:2}}</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" ng-model="object2.valor" ng-init="object2.valor=object.valor" ng-value="object.valor" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <br /> Object : {{object}}
    <br /> Object 2 : {{object2}}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

O aquí en plunker: https://plnkr.co/HWqS6lcrRfw1UNJvztYA

Comment: pues no se porque no funciona, me podrias ayudar con la alternativa

Comment: @sirdaiz mejor primero decime que queres hacer y yo en funcion de eso te explico como y porque.

Comment: Tengo un form apra guardar con el valor original y modificado, no tengo ningun error en consola pero tu solución funciona pero en mi caso no, por eso creo que con la alternativa podria funcionarme pero no se porque no son independientes

Comment: @sirdiaz esa es una de las ventajas que tiene angular, no son independientes porque estas asignando el mismo objeto a variables distintas por lo cual quedan referenciados. Para solucionar esto tendrias que bien asignar primitivos (int, string, bool, etc) o bien utilizar `$scope.object2 = angular.copy(valor)` para romper este referenciamiento y obtener una copia independiente del objeto.

Comment: gracias el angular.copy me sirvio